# Why am I getting this FedEx API error 'The given grant_type is not supported. Please modify your request and try again'

Tags: php, web-services, curl, fedex

I'm using this PHP code:

```php
$service_url = 'https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token';
   $curl = curl_init($service_url);
   $curl_post_data = array(
       "content-type" => 'application/json',
        "grant_type" => 'client_credentials',
        "client_id" => '<client_id>',
        "client_secret" => '<client_secret>',
        );
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
   $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);

echo $curl_response;
```

And getting this response:

```json
{"transactionId": "e147dc65-b09c-4586-be2d-4da3beafa8ed","errors":[{"code":"BAD.REQUEST.ERROR","message":"The given grant_type is not supported. Please modify your request and try again."}]}%
```

I have the service_url, client_id, and client_secret as they are in the FedEx developer site.  I'm not sure where the issue is.

Comment: Could the `grant_type` possibly need to be `csp_credentials` instead? Those are the only two options that are noted in the API: `client_credentials - should be used for customers.
csp_credentials - should be used for Compatible Service Provider customers.`

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar error when working with Postman because I was using the wrong content-type (`form-data` instead of `x-www-form-urlencoded`). Make sure to set your content-type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.